# Routing with Phalcon using Nginx + php5-fpm, file not found

Tags: nginx, routes, phalcon

I've been pulling my hair out trying to fix this issue. I can't add routes correctly, or else nginx isn't working with phalcon properly.

Doesn't help that the phalcon tuts are all apache based.

Problem: I can access `http://localhost` and be given the index.php fine, but I get a "file not found" when I try access localhost/signup.

index.php
    try {

```
//Register an autoloader
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();
$loader->registerDirs(array(
    '../application/controllers/',
    '../application/models/'
))->register();

$di = new Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();

//Setup the view component
$di->set('view', function(){
    $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();
    $view->setViewsDir('../application/views/');
    return $view;
});

$di->set('url', function(){
    $url = new Phalcon\Mvc\Url();
    $url->setBaseUri('/');
    return $url;
});

$di->set('router', function() {
    $router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router();
    $router->setUriSource(Phalcon\Mvc\Router::URI_SOURCE_SERVER_REQUEST_URI);
    $router->add(
        '/signup',
        array(
            "controller" => "signup",
            "action" => "index"
        )
    );

    return $router;
});

//Handle the request
$application = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Application($di);
echo $application->handle()->getContent();

} catch(\Phalcon\Exception $e) {
  echo "PhalconException: ", $e->getMessage();
}
```

nginx config

```
server {
listen   80;
server_name  Tikarta-berkshelf;
root /var/www/;
index public/index.php;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
}


location ~ \.php$ {
#try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

fastcgi_index public/index.php;
include fastcgi_params;
}
location ~ /\.ht {
deny all;
}

}
```

SignupController.php

```
<?php


class SignupController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{

public function indexAction()
{
    echo "hello";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong document root was the issue here. Nginx config should have been

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  Tikarta-berkshelf;
    root /var/www/public;
    index index.php;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

    location / {
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    # if file exists return it right away
    if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
    }

    # otherwise rewrite it
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?_url=/$1 last;
    break;
    }
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
    #try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: By posting a question you receive a portion of mental power rays from the outer space that help you find an answer by yourself. Fact.

Comment: Lol yea it's called the rubber duck phenomenon in my work when you try explain to someone what the problem is, and the answer becomes apparent.

You'd be as good having a rubber duck on your desk and asking it lol.